# why does .htaccess work this way?

Tags: .htaccess

I've noticed a particular behavior when trying to add password protection to a certain page of a website. If I create users and passwords as described here:

http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/

and attempt to log on, everything works fine on the first login attempt, from the initial computer. However, thereafter if I try to login from a different computer the password is never accepted and the prompt endlessly appears for a username and password.

My .htaccess file is very simple:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Could someone help clear up cause for this behavior?

Comment: That should not happen - it is likely that there is a misconfiguration, or the .htpasswd file is not actually readable, or another browser is caching some previous HTTP auth header configuration.  Test out your current (hopefully working) setup in a private/incognito browsing window. Does it work there?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski that does not seem to work. also attempting to create a new user with a new password and trying that as the first ever log attempt fails...I am using bluehost which comes with a ton of preconfigured files. im thinking maybe that's the cause

Comment: Is SSL involved on your site?

Comment: @PanamaJack no SSL certificate is currently being used

Comment: The  AuthUserFile path is absolute, or relative to the ServerRoot ?

Comment: @Croises absolute

Comment: Absolute with the file name (not only path to)...

Comment: @Croises yes absolute with a file name. also, i redid everything from scratch, just in case and tried what suggested. Both the incognito and the regular login attempt worked from the same computer